# debugging android device from Chrome screen layout not showing correctly

Tags: android, google-chrome, device, inspect

I'm trying to debug my Android Ionic app which was installed on phone from Android studio. When I select Inspect my app, then google chrome screen layout is not rendering correctly. Please see the screen shot.[screen shot of chrome after i select Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTRqq.png). When I try to debug same app on emulator, then chrome inspect is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a breaking change in chromium and chrome, the only solution is to revert to an older version, more discussion is here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/qWg3OAGUIOY/P-K_wpE9CgAJ